# store values at pointer index?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to teach myself C by completing random projects that I find online, but I ran into a tiny problem. Currently learning pointers. How do I correctly store a user inputted value at an index in a pointer array of char?

```
int i, numberPeople = 5;

char **firstName = (char**) malloc(numberPeople*sizeof(char));
char **lastName = (char**) malloc(numberPeople*sizeof(char));
double *scores = (double*) malloc(numberPeople*sizeof(double));


// allocating space for each individual person
for (i = 0; i < numberPeople; i++) { 
    firstName[i] = (char*) malloc(MAXIMUM_DATA_LENGTH*sizeof(char)); // MAXIMUM_DATA_LENGTH = 50
    lastName[i] = (char*) malloc(MAXIMUM_DATA_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
    scores[i] = *(double*) malloc(1*sizeof(double));
}

// begin user input for each person
for (i = 0; i < numberPeople; i++) {
    printf("Person #%d \n\n", i + 1);

    printf("First Name: ");
    scanf("%s", firstName[i]);

    printf("Last Name: ");
    scanf("%s", lastName[i]); // crashes on person[2] ==> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (EXC_I386_GPFLT)

    printf("Score: ");
    scanf("%lf", &scores[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

My program always stops/crashes when I input the lastName of person[2]. The error that shows is this --> **"EXC_BAD_ACCESS (EXC_I386_GPFLT)"**.

Comment: Learn to use your debugger. Side note: you need to use `structs` for this kind of project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,

```
char **firstName = (char**) malloc(numberPeople*sizeof(char));
char **lastName = (char**) malloc(numberPeople*sizeof(char));
```

you need to use

```
char **firstName = (char**) malloc(numberPeople*sizeof(char *));
char **lastName = (char**) malloc(numberPeople*sizeof(char *));
```

because you must store an array of pointer on char array. So your allocation size is too tiny : `sizeof(char)` is 1, you cannot store an address on 1 byte.

Comment: `char` is a byte not an octet

Comment: Edited. But I can bet 1 byte is 1 octet on the OP's computer ;)

Comment: Sure, and on 99.99% of computers ;)

Answer (score 0):

what about this :

```
int i, numberPeople = 5;

char *firstName = malloc(numberPeople*sizeof(char));
char *lastName = malloc(numberPeople*sizeof(char));
double *scores = malloc(numberPeople*sizeof(double));

// begin user input for each person
for (i = 0; i < numberPeople; i++) {
    printf("Person #%d \n\n", i + 1);

    printf("First Name: ");
    scanf("%s",&firstName[i]);

    printf("Last Name: ");
    scanf("%s",&lastName[i]);

    printf("Score: ");
    scanf("%lf",&scores[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: You have only allocated one `char` string each for the first and last names. In your example the memory allocated is 5 bytes for each, so any name longer than 4 bytes goes out of bounds. Try running it with valgrind. Next your `for` loop indexes the start address within the variables, you do not have an array of names. If you entered three first names 'Amy, Bert, Camille' when you print out firstName you get 'ABCamille' - you have written to the same variable each time, just starting one byte further from the starting address.